# How can I access to UITextView from an ARScene thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading, uiview, xcode9, arkit

I'm trying to hide a `UITextView` when the floor is detected in `ARScene`. The code is as below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    ...

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

    // runs on floor detection
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
            myTextView.isHidden = true // Error from Main Thread Checker 
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

However, it doesn't hide `myTextView` but produces an error saying *`UIView.hidden` must be used from main thread only*. I'd like to know what the right approach would be. I'm new to Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `renderer` runs in background thread. You need to run all code related to ui in main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    myTextView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: you just solved my issue. thanks!! can i use this static method as many times as needed? or is this just a quick fix?

Comment: This sends your code to execute from main thread. So you can use it every time you need to run codes in main thread from inside background thread

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Not question the fact it runs in the background thread, but I'm not able to find any documentation stating that.  I've a snippet of code here that works ok without going on the main thread.

Comment: @Chi-HwaMichaelTing can you share the code snippet?

Comment: func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if let planeNode = self?.createARPlaneNode(planeAnchor: planeAnchor, color: UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) {
                node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            }
        }
        
    }

Comment: Your code inside `createARPlaneNode(planeAnchor):`, if I am not wrong, doesnot handle UI. So it should run normally. And handling scenekit codes run inside `renderer` thread